# Batch Programming: Invoking functions and retrieving results multiple times while looping

Tags: batch-file

I've a **batch** script in which I *loop* trough all the *filenames* in a *folder* and then I invoke a command in order to remove the **extension** from the *filename*. I'd like to store at every iteration the filename (without extension) in a variable named `result` for later reuse.

The `RemoveExtension` function works fine. However I'm not able to retrieve the **result** and store it in the `_result` variable. When I print it, it's always empty. Thanks for your help!

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_result="
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%~1\*.txt" /b') DO (
   echo.filepath: "%~1\%%i"
   call :RemoveExtension "%%i"
   echo._result: "%_result%"  // The "_result" variable is always EMPTY ""
)
goto :eof

:RemoveExtension
SETLOCAL
   REM echo "%~1"
   set "filename=%~1"

   :loop
      if "%filename:~-1%" NEQ "." (
         set "filename=%filename:~0,-1%
         goto :loop
      ) 
   set "filename=%filename:~0,-1%"
   echo "%filename%"
ENDLOCAL & set "_result=%filename%"
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...much simpler way to remove the extension. Because you are changing `_result` inside a `FOR` loop, you need to access it using `!` instead of `%`.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "_result="
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%~1\*.txt" /b') DO (
   ECHO.filepath: "%~1\%%i"
   SET _result=%%~ni
   ECHO._result: "!_result!"
)
```